# Printing Getter methods

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm having a problem trying to print out Getter methods in a switch statement from two different classes. A template (Donut) class and a chocolate class can anyone help me out?

```
public class Donut {
  private boolean sprinkles;
  private String flavor;
  private boolean filled;
  private String frostingFlavor;
  private boolean hole;
  private String name;
  public Donut(String name) {
      this.name=name;
  }
  public void setSprinkles(boolean sprinkles) {
      this.sprinkles=sprinkles;
  }
  public void setFlavor(String flavor) {
      this.flavor=flavor;
  }
  public void setHole(boolean hole) {
      this.hole=hole;
  }
  public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
      this.filled=filled;
  }
  public void frostingFlavor(String frostingFlavor) {
      this.frostingFlavor=frostingFlavor;
  }
  public String Donut() {
      return name;
  }
  public boolean Sprinkles() {
      return sprinkles;
  }
  public String getFlavor() {
      return flavor;
  }
  public boolean Hole() {
      return hole;
  }
  public boolean Filled() {
      return filled;
  }
  public String frostingFlavor() {
      return frostingFlavor;
  }
}
```

And here's the class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Chocolate {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      Donut chocolate=new Donut("chocolate");//Sets donut name to chocolate
      chocolate.setFlavor("chocolate");//sets donut flavor to chocolate
      chocolate.setHole(true);//donut object has a hole
      chocolate.setFilled(false);//donut object isn't filled
      chocolate.frostingFlavor("vanilla");//donut frosting flavor is vanilla
      chocolate.setSprinkles(true);//donut object has sprinkles
      Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);//scanner/imput header
      System.out.println("What would you like to know?");//start of switch statement
      System.out.println("1. Donut Flavor");
      System.out.println("2. Donut Frosting Flavor");
      System.out.println("3. Donut Sprinkles");
      System.out.println("4. Filled");
      System.out.println("5. Sprinkles");
      System.out.println("6. Donut Hole\n");
      int choice=kbReader.nextInt();
      switch(choice) {
          case 1://Donut Flavor
          System.out.println(Donut.getFlavor());
      }
  }
}
```

It'd be awesome if anyone could help me out,Thanks.

Comment: Change `System.out.println(Donut.getFlavor());` to `System.out.println(chocolate.getFlavor());`

Comment: You have not implement the getter method `getFlavor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `getFlavor()` method is not a static method you can't do
`Donut.getFlavor()` but you have to do `someDonutObject.getFlavor()`. Fortunately you already have a Donut object so you can just do `choclate.getFlavor()`. It has to be like this, because you want to know the flavor of that specific donut, every donut might have a different flavor. If you had a value which was the same for each donut (for example the price) you could make that a static method.
One more thing: Usually methods start with a lowercase char and if the methods just returns a value it usually also starts with a 'get' followed by what you return. You might want to change `Donut()` to `getName()`. There is an exception made for boolean values sometimes so `Filled()` might become `isFilled()`.

Comment: another question I had was if i wanted to use a whiel(true){} statement to loop the switch statement how could I have a line of code to have the user exit the loop?

Comment: Usually you want to do that using `break;`. If you want to break out of a nested loop you might want to take a look at break with lables. (Very rarely used though)
In generall a while(true) loop is not recommended; there is probably a way to create a loop with a proper ending condition.